# How can I use OrderingFilter along with other Filterset filtering on a model

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a model lets say `ObservedMoves`. This model is referenced in many queries inside my views. So instead of applying the filters that I want directly inside each view I have them abstracted inside a filterclass let's say `ObservedMovesFilters` that subclasses `django_filters.Filterset` and has a meta field `model = ObservedMoves`.

Now what I want to do is to enable the user to specify the ordering field when giving a request. For that I plan to use DRF's `OrderingFilter`. If I try to subclass the `OrderingFilter` class instead of the `Filterset` class the filters don't work. If I specify `OrderingFilter` as the default filter backend again the filters don't work.

In DRF's documentation the only method presented is specifying inside a view the alternative filter back end and also specify the ordering parameters but I want to avoid explicitly defining it in every view that queries that model. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify another field on the `ViewSet` called `filter_backends`

```
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,filters.OrderingFilter,)
```

e.g.

```
from rest_framework import filters
import django_filters

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    [...]

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    #vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = UserFilter
    ordering = ('username',)
```

Comment: This partially solves the problem since I still have to specify the backend explicitly in every view or viewset but at least it works.

Comment: You can probably sub-class the `ModelViewSet`(or whatever) and add a `filter_backends` field that would be the default for your models.

Answer (score 13):

If I'm understanding you correctly you don't have to add `filter_backends` to every `ViewSet` like the other answer says.

You can just set up your default filter backends in your `settings.py` file like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
    )
}
```